# QT android include no such file or directory

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk

I've created a new QT project for android and desktop but when I try to build for android I get the following errors

```
:-1: error: error: Files\QT\5.7\android_x86\include: No such file or directory
:-1: error: error: Files\QT\5.7\android_x86\include\QtWidgets: No such file or directory
:-1: error: error: Files\QT\5.7\android_x86\include\QtGui: No such file or directory
:-1: error: error: Files\QT\5.7\android_x86\include\QtCore: No such file or directory
:-1: error: error: Files\QT\5.7\android_x86\mkspecs\android-g++: No such file or directory
```

my .pro file

```
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Test
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY =
```

I have both x86 and x86_64 ndk.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked Tools->Options->Devices->Android to see if all the paths are correct?

Comment: Yes, they are correct.

Comment: @SaNtoRiaN Do you have any spaces in paths? And do you have access permissions?

Comment: in sdk and ndk, no spaces. but in original QT files, I changed installation path to another driver with path: D:\Program Files\QT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reinstall original Qt into path without spaces or non-latin symbols.
I think there was such recommendation somewhere in Qt documentation.

Comment: @MaxPashkov I'm having the same problem but I don't understand the answer. Could you please give me more detailed instructions? My Qt is installed in /opt/qt

Comment: @JetonThaçi I don't think your situation is quite the same as for topic starter because he had dealed with Windows and your path /opt/qt tells me that you are using Linux. Also SaNtoRiaN had installed his Qt in "Program Files" directory whitch has spacing between "Program" and "Files" so build could not start. Need more details in your case to understand what went wrong.